# EKS Ingress Nginx Load Balancer Integrate with WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have deployed Ingress Nginx on AWS EKS cluster. Ingress controller and Service are deployed as components. Therefor an AWS network load balancer has been provision for the Ingress Nginx controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.36.0-external
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-external
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-external
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.49.0-external
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm-external
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-external
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-external
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-external
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-external
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-external
```

Traffic is coming through the NLB and TLS terminated by the ingress controller.

What I want to do is integrate the AWS WAF with the Ingress. There is a method for the AWS ALB but is there a method to integrate the WAF for the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As of now you cannot set the NLB target type to 'alb'. You can [manually](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/application-load-balancer-type-target-group-for-network-load-balancer/) setup the NLB and add an ALB behind it; and associate WAF with the added ALB.